# Functional component state is not carried into the functions of the component

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component as below to draw some polygons on a Google Map. I removed operational details and left only bare minimum.

In the console log of useEffect with polygons dependency, console shows the correctly updated polygons, which tells me that this is not any asynchronous issue. But in the initMap function it is showing the polygons array as **empty array**. As an alternative, if I provide the polygons array to initMap as a parameter, it is passed correctly

I though, state of a component must be accessible within its own methods, NO ? I have no clue how to fix this :/ Any ideas ?

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

function MyMap(props) {
  const [polygons, setPolygons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Polygons updated useeffect : " + polygons);
    if (window.initMap !== undefined) {
      window.initMap();
    }
  }, [polygons]);

  function initMap() {
    const zoom = props.props.zoom;
    const center = props.props.center;

    const tmpMap = new window.google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("google-map"),
      {
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: false,
      }
    );

    if (polygons !== undefined) {
      polygons.forEach((polygon) => {
        return new window.google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: polygon,
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          map: tmpMap,
        });
      });
    }

  mapElement = (
    <div
      className="map-container"
      id="google-map"
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
    >
      {arrayObject}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <section className="map-wrapper-container">
      {mapElement}
      <Helmet>
        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          async={true}
          defer={true}
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap"
        />
      </Helmet>
    </section>
  );
}
export default MyMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to change the state of `polygons`, you should use `setPolygons` instead of just re-define the array, since it will not trigger re-render and React will act as `polygons` is not changed at all. I'd suggest this:

```
  if (polygons !== undefined) {
    setPolygons(prev => prev.map(((polygon) => {
      return new window.google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: polygon,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        map: tmpMap,
      });
    })));
  }
```

Second, in my opinion it's safer passing `polygons` to `initMap()`. But in case you don't want to, you will not need to pass `polygons` as dependency for the `useEffect`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ngtrthinh , I could use the array as a parameter; yet my concern is about the concept here; why the polygons' state is not accessible in the initMap function. What could I possible be missing ?

Comment: @GeoSystems It IS accessible, the thing that I think went wrong is how you change the state of `polygons`.
First of all, `polygons` will be initialize as `[]`, then React will render the component (which doesn't have the map yet). After the render, `useEffect` runs and "change" your `polygons`, but React won't re-render (as I mentioned above), so in your screen only the old `polygons` value is applied.

Comment: quoted from [official useEffect docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#examples-dependencies): "If you specify the dependencies, your Effect runs after the initial render and after re-renders with changed dependencies."

So the run order will be: init -> render -> useEffect (-> should be a render to show what changed in useEffect)

Your useEffect doesn't "change" any state since you've only changed the value of `polygons` array, the address of the array (the one that React cares) is still the same. So React acts like nothing change, and your change will not be reflected.

Comment: OK, I dont see it that way. I had a hunch and tested this :

Comment: OK, after some further research, I found out that react changes the memory references to the state objects; i.e. the references to the same variable (polygons) are different in the MyMap component and initMap function. If I understand it correctly, I find this concept very confusing, particularly as JS abstracts the whole memory management and object references are not traceable.